# How to create React app in machine not connected to internet

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I should set up a React project in a production machine in my company, but it is off to internet because of security things. How can I create React project in offline mode?

I installed Node.js offline and set it up successfully. But npx not working.

```
$ npx create-react-app frontend
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: read ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/wlsadmin/.npm/_logs/2022-08-19T07_29_21_998Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: `create-react-app` installs dependencies - from internet. You need to deploy built application.

Answer (score 1):

You need internet to download dependencies

The easiest way would be to create the app from a computer having internet and then transfer the folder with a USB hard drive

Comment: It works. Besides I created it in a windows environment. Then carried all to linux machine. and it is up. just I gave execute rigth to "frontend/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts